# IntelliJ/PyCharm Project Structure for Existing Python Application

Tags: python, intellij-idea, flask, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I recently purchased the IntelliJ-IDEA 13 for use of downloading the Python plugin (which I am told has the same code-base as PyCharm) and working on a python web project (specifically Flask). I thought it would be a near seamless transfer from Sublime text but I am having some trouble.

So here is my problem: I am trying to import an existing Python application (as said earlier that is using Flask) but I cannot set the file correct file structure when importing my project.

My existing/current project is set up as so (it is modeled after most Flask applications):

```
/Base Directory
    /app
        /static
            *CSS/JS/IMGs go here*
        /templates
            *Templates go here*
        __init__.py
        forms/models/routes.py
    run.py
```

If you want to see the actual project, it is available on my [GitHub Project Page](https://github.com/EpicDavi/SpeedRunTimersWebsite).

IntelliJ apparently has the feature to import existing code into a project, however whenever I go to `Import Project`, and selecting my `Base Directory` folder, it always turns out like this:

[image: When I try to Import a Project]

When I create a `New Project -> Flask Project (or any other Python project type)` it ends up looking like this:

[image: When I create a New Flask Project]

The latter is more of what I am looking for (seeing the other files inside of the project, instead of just the root folder).

**So my question is:** Is there a way to adapt my current file structure to work with IntelliJ/PyCharm or vice-versa (and be able to work with the other files)? Or is there a quick fix or mistake that I am making?

Thank you in advance, and remember my project page is [here](https://github.com/EpicDavi/SpeedRunTimersWebsite).

-*EpicDavi*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Old Solution

I have found a temporary solution for this for the time being.

I ended up just creating a new project and copying the files from the old one into the new one. This lets me get the project panel like the other projects but is still a hassle moving files around.

This is of course not perfect, seeing as my original project is on GitHub and will have to synchronize the files any time I want to commit.

#### Edit. Newer Solution

Instead of doing the above, I have found that if you create a new Python project inside of the directory of choice (in my case being the `Base Directory`) with no other settings, it will set up the project in that area with the necessary files. Everything is running smoothly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure but wouldn't the Refactor > Move be an option for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flask you need: **Settings -> Project -> Project Structure** and Mark as **Sourses** you project folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMYbK.jpg)